# In Azure while assigning ip to the instance i'm getting error

Tags: powershell, azure, ubuntu-12.04

In Azure How to configure reserve ip to the instance?
While configuring with powershell
I'm seeing the below error

```
New-AzureVMConfig -Name "ubuntu" -InstanceSize "Small" -ImageName "Ubuntu*"| Add-AzureProvisioningConfig -Window
s -AdminUsername "ubuntu" -Password "dangerous09"| New-AzureVM -ServiceName "newinstance.localdomain" -ReservedIPName "MyReserv
edIP" -Location "South Central US"
```

Error:

```
WARNING: The specified DNS name is already taken.
VERBOSE: 5:10:07 PM - Begin Operation: New-AzureVM - Create Deployment with VM ubuntu
New-AzureVM : BadRequest: The supplied password must be 8-123 characters long and meet password complexity
requirements.
At line:1 char:167
+ New-AzureVMConfig -Name "ubuntu" -InstanceSize "Small" -ImageName "Ubuntu*"| Add ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureVM], CloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.IaaS.PersistentVMs.NewAzureVMCommand
```

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I have fixed it.

```
New-AzureVMConfig -Name "ubuntutest" -InstanceSize "Basic_A0" –ImageName "ubuntutestimage-20150611-543899" | New-AzureVM -ServiceName "ubuntutestimage" –ReservedIPName " demoreservedip " -Location "West US”

OperationDescription OperationId OperationStatus 
-----New-AzureVM 2e8c084b-0077-8551-9734-d1f2f3c3c1d2 Succeeded
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message seems pretty self explanatory:

> BadRequest: The supplied password must be 8-123 characters long and meet password complexity
>   requirements.

For a Windows VM the following are the complexity requirements, I assume the same applies to the Ubuntu VM:

> The password that is input when prompted above must meet password
>   complexity requirements of at least 3 of the following: 1 UPPER case
>   letter, 1 lower case letter, 1 number and/or 1 symbol

Looks like you are only meeting 2 of the requirements (lower case letter and number).  Try adding an upper case letter and/or a symbol.

Comment: I tried with complex password, so that bad request gone.still DNS name already exists is there..could you help me with example .

Comment: If the answer resolved your password problem then mark it as answered and then start a new thread for whatever new issue you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

For a start, if you are attempting to provision a Linux based VM, you need to change the "-Windows" parameter to "-Linux" in the "Add-AzureProvisioningConfig" line.

Comment: Even though I have changed getting the below error  :        Add-AzureProvisioningConfig : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'ubuntu'.
At line:1 char:106
+ ... isioningConfig -ubuntu -AdminUsername "ubuntu" -Password "dangerous09"| New-Azur ...
+                    ~~~~~~~